# VSCdoe, the shortcut key of deleteWordPartRight conflicts with the shortcut of task manager

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In Vscode 1.25.0, when I press ctrl+alt+delete, I wish to delete word part right. But Windows task manager is opened actually.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can [change the default shortcut](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings).

1. Go to **File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts**
2. Search for `deleteWordPartRight`.
3. Click the edit button to the left of the command you want to update.
4. Add the new keybinding.